# ‘Shined’ vs ‘Shone’

Tags: grammar

Is this a good example of the differentiation between ‘shined’ and ‘shone’? ‘Shined’ needs an object; ‘shone’ does not.

‘He shined his shoes while the sun shone brightly.’

Comment: Could you please expand on this. Are you asking whether the strong and weak preterites of the verb to shine have acquired distinct meanings or usages? Or are you asking whether shined can be used transitively and shine cannot. Asking whether something is a good example of an unarticulated difference (keep it simple), assumes that difference to be true.

Comment: The causative (i.e, transitive) verb _shine_ is regular, like most derived causatives, but the continuous state verb _shine_ is irregular, with _shone_ as its past tense and past participle. That means that if it means _make something shine_ it gets -ed for the past tense (shine your shoes), but if it just means be shiny, it gets shone instead of shined.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> The causative (i.e, transitive) verb *shine* is regular, like most derived causatives, but the continuous state verb *shine* is irregular, with *shone* as its past tense and past participle. That means that if it means *make something shine* it gets -ed for the past tense (shine your shoes), but if it just means be shiny, it gets shone instead of shined.