# Outshined or outshone?

Tags: grammar

He outshined the competition.
He outshone the competition.

Is ‘outshined’ or ‘outshone’ correct here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outshone or outshined?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200784/outshone-or-outshined) See also [‘Shined’ vs ‘Shone’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/522508/shined-vs-shone) and [The sun has shined/shone its shine?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299036/the-sun-has-shined-shone-its-shine/299051#299051), among others.

Comment: If it has an object, it's regular. Regular verbs add _-ed_ for the past.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said. Hence we normally say a street urchin ***shined shoes** for a living*, rather than that he ***shone shoes***. But personally I'd probably say I ***shone a torch*** on something, rather than ***shined*** it.

Comment: *Outshined* sounds wrong to me. In AmE, if you shine a source of illumination *on* something, the past tense is often *shined*. But here, a source of illumination is *brighter* than something, which is a different kind of object. So I would use *outshone*. And [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=outshined%2Coutshone+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coutshined%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutshone%3B%2Cc0) agrees with me.

Comment: The verb shine has two past-tense forms: shined and shone. Both are acceptable.  Some (but not all) sources recommend using shined when the verb has an object and shone when it does not.

Comment: @MichaelHavey:  There are two past-tense forms, but they're not equally acceptable in all sentences. We very rarely say [shone his shoes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shone+his+shoes%2Cshined+his+shoes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshined%20his%20shoes%3B%2Cc0) or [the sun shined](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sun+shone%2C+sun+shined&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csun%20shone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csun%20shined%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: The degree of interchangeability of 'shined' and 'shone' is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Should I say 'Go get your shine box'?

Comment: If it was a car polishing competition then "outshined" is correct.

Comment: But do not confuse "shone" with "shown".

Comment: @GEdgar - do not confuse "shone" with "shown" - I hear that in American-read audiobooks.

Comment: @JohnLawler Not all transitive verbs are regular. Some examples of verbs which can be transitive, and which are irregular even when transitive: begin, bid/bade, bind, bite, bleed, blow, break, breed, bring, buy. Outshine likewise.

Comment: @RosieF You misunderstood. John just meant that the transitive version of *shine* is regular, not that all transitive verbs are.

Answer (score 2):

Either is acceptable. Both have a history of transitive use.

First, the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) has more results for **outshone** (91) than **outshined** (27). In both search results are several instances where they take direct objects and function as transitive verbs. For example:

> Well, you have definitely **outshined** and outdone us all. ("Maggie Rodriguez^s senior prom in 1987, "The Early Show on CBS, May 9, 2008.)
>
> "The pride he had in his family **outshone** the success he had in business, " his brother Frank said. ("No More Phantom Wedding Guest, No Beach or Tower-Top Proposals," New York Times, February 12, 2002.)

---

Second, dictionaries vary in what form they report. The Oxford English Dictionary ("[outshine, v.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/133962)") documents the past participle and past tense form as such:

> Inflections:   Past tense and past participle **outshone**;

Examples after the early 17th century only include *outshone*, not *outshined*. For example:

> 1987   R. Ingalis End of Trag. 184   She **outshone** the light-reflecting surfaces of nature.
>
> 1989   TV Extra (Brisbane) 30 Apr. 4/2   They even go so far as to hint that David **outshone** Faye when it came to acting.

Merriam-Webster ("[outshone](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outshone?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)") is more equivocal, allowing for either **outshone** or **outshined**:

> **outshone** \ˌau̇t-​ˈshōn, especially British  -​ˈshän\ or **outshined**; outshining

And this example shows a transitive usage for **outshone**:

> **outshone** most of the other films in quality

---

In other words, you're free to go with whichever one you think sounds better, or to pick whichever basis of evidence (frequency; a favorite dictionary or publication) you like.